# android widget flash light on off

Tags: android

Below is XML file.

how can i get "**Update**" tag value from xml parse

i get all other value fron menu tag but only i wants Update tag value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>

<update>10/10/2013</update> 

<item>
<title>Save 75¢ off any (1) DESITIN®</title> 
<thumbnail>http://www-in.com/Coupons/images/2001_1_2_1_1.jpg</thumbnail> 
<link>http://4shared.com</link> 
<description>Duis semper tellus non diam accumsan interdum.</description> 
<saving>0.75</saving> 
<category>Baby</category> 
<validdate>31/08/2013</validdate> 
<featured>yes</featured> 
<type>Offers</type> 
<visibility>free</visibility> 
</item>
```

-   
'